# Failure to find Chrome Browser Window using Microsoft CodedUI for automated tests

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4
Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m
Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System
Coded UITest Builder 11.0.60315.1

Our software team is creating an ASP.NET web application, and the customer has requested that we use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with Microsoft CodedUI to run automated tests.

I ran our ASP.NET application in Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m
I took steps to use the Microsoft CodedUI to record some Browser-user interaction steps on our ASP.NET application which ultimately led to generating some code.
The following is the generated code based on the recorded Brower-user interaction that I conducted on our ASP.NET Web Application

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by coded UI test builder.
//      Version: 11.0.0.0
//
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject
{
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
    using Mouse = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse;
    using MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls;

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "11.0.60315.1")]
    public partial class UIMap
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// RecordedMethod1
        /// </summary>
        public void RecordedMethod1()
        {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinClient uIChromeLegacyWindowClient = this.UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow.UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow.UIChromeLegacyWindowClient;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Chrome Legacy Window' client
        Mouse.Click(uIChromeLegacyWindowClient, new Point(151, 25));

        // Click 'Chrome Legacy Window' client
        Mouse.Click(uIChromeLegacyWindowClient, new Point(150, 35));

        // Click 'Chrome Legacy Window' client
        Mouse.Click(uIChromeLegacyWindowClient, new Point(709, 90));
    }

    #region Properties
    public UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow == null))
            {
                this.mUIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow = new UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow();
            }
            return this.mUIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow mUIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "11.0.60315.1")]
public class UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow : WinWindow
{

    public UIJigsawBetaEnviromentWindow()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Jigsaw [Beta Enviroment] - Google Chrome";
     //   this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Jigsaw";
       this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Chrome_WidgetWin_1";
       // this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Chrome";
       this.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw [Beta Enviroment] - Google Chrome");
     //   this.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowWindow == null))
            {
                this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowWindow = new UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow(this);
            }
            return this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowWindow;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow mUIChromeLegacyWindowWindow;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "11.0.60315.1")]
public class UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow : WinWindow
{

    public UIChromeLegacyWindowWindow(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "144212160";
       this.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw [Beta Enviroment] - Google Chrome");
      //  this.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinClient UIChromeLegacyWindowClient
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient == null))
            {
                this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient = new WinClient(this);
                #region Search Criteria
               this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Chrome Legacy Window";
          //      this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Chrome";
                this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw [Beta Enviroment] - Google Chrome");
            //    this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient.WindowTitles.Add("Jigsaw");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinClient mUIChromeLegacyWindowClient;
    #endregion
}
```

}

Microsoft CodedUI is throwing Error because it fails to see 'Chrome Legacy Window'

I ran the code, but I get the following Error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException was     unhandled by user code
  HResult=-268111872
  Message=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.     Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'Client'
Name:  'Chrome Legacy Window'

  Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
  BasicMessage=The playback failed to find the control with the given search     properties.
  RootElement=""
  StackTrace:
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException    (COMException ex, IPlaybackContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException        (COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException    (SystemException exception, IPlaybackContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException    (SystemException exception, String queryId)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant    (String     queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean     useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search    (ISearchArgument searchArg)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindPrivate()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<Find>b__d()
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1     function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean     logAsAction)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Find()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyPrivate    (String     propertyName)
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass11.<GetProperty>b    __10()
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1     function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean     logAsAction)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String     propertyName)
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ALUtility.GetTechElementFromUITestControl    (UITestControl uiTestControl)
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ActionExecutorManager.GetActionExecutor    (UITestControl uiControl)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation    (UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point     relativeCoordinate)
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Click>b__5()
       at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1     function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean     logAsAction)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl     control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl     control, Point relativeCoordinate)
       at JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject.UIMap.RecordedMethod1() in     d:\EMIS\JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject\JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject\UIMap.cs:line 42
       at JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in     d:\EMIS\JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject\JigsawEMISTCodedUITestProject\CodedUITest1.cs:line 30
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
       Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       StackTrace:
            at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants    (String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth)
            at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String     queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException, Boolean     resetSkipStep)
            at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String     queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean resetSkipStep)
            at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String     queryId, Int32 depth)
            at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String     queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
       InnerException:
```

Do I need to install some drivers for popular browsers ( i.e Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, IE, etc.) ?
I restarted my development computer a couple times, but still have same problem.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a Selenium framework that was ported to run with Coded UI by a developer at Microsoft, which you can find [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d), that will use the Selenium components to run the tests in Chrome or Firefox.  IE is handled by the Coded UI itself, so if your `BrowserWindow.BrowserType` is "IE", then it'll just run the vanilla Coded UI that's shipped with your Visual Studio.

The Q&A section of that page is where you'll find the most support for questions about the tool itself, but if you have trouble getting started, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/05/run-your-coded-ui-tests-against-chrome-using-the-selenium-toolkit.aspx) was very helpful.